# Nginx with virtual sites, all rewrites and all returns give only the error "cyclic redirect error"

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx webserver with 3 virtual sites(including the main real site). Using http simple works fine, using https(without redirecting) works fine.
I want to redirect all http request to https, even for containers(also known as virtual hosts).
But every client(firefox, links) give 301 error cyclic redirect.

This is my configuration

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
events {
    worker_connections 768;
}
http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off; 
    more_clear_headers Server;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/http2.mysite.priv.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/http2.mysite.priv.key;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log ;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    gzip on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

the default site

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl ;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name http2.mysite.priv;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

the first container/virtual host

```
server {
    listen 80; 
    listen [::]:80 ;
    listen 443 ssl;
    root /var/www/html/virtual1.mysite.priv;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name virtual1.mysite.priv;
    rewrite ^(.*) https://virtual1.mysite.priv$1 permanent;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    
    location /images {
        autoindex on;
    }
}
```

I have also tried the "return" method instead of rewrite but give me the same result.

```
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

What I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one server block listening on port 80 with your return statement. Remove the `listen 80` statements from all of the other server blocks.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```